# returns [] when passed an empty string and returns the lengths when passed multiple words

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

so i need to write a function that gets the length of each individual words on the array that will pass these conditions

```
it("returns [] when passed an empty string", () => {
    expect(getWordLengths("")).to.eql([]);
  });
  it("returns an array containing the length of a single word", () => {
    expect(getWordLengths("woooo")).to.eql([5]);
  });
  it("returns the lengths when passed multiple words", () => {
    expect(getWordLengths("hello world")).to.eql([5, 5]);
  });
  it("returns lengths for longer sentences", () => {
    expect(getWordLengths("like a bridge over troubled water")).to.eql([
      4,
      1,
      6,
      4,
      8,
      5
    ]);
```

my initial solution works but I want to use .map instead. So far I got

```
let x = str.split(' ');
console.log(x.map(nums => nums.length))
```

but that won't return [] when passed through an empty array

Comment: it just gives me this error code... AssertionError: expected undefined to deeply equal []

Answer (score 2):

For the empty string, you'll get `[ "" ]` and the `.map` will return `[ 0 ]`,

Filter out the `0` values :

```
str.split(" ").map(nums => nums.length).filter(e => e);
```

```js
const getWordLengths = str => {
  return str
    .split(" ")
    .map(nums => nums.length)
    .filter(e => e);
};

console.log(getWordLengths("")); //? []
console.log(getWordLengths("woooo")); //? [5]
console.log(getWordLengths("hello world")); //? [5, 5]
console.log(getWordLengths("like a bridge over troubled water")); //? [4, 1, 6, 4, 8, 5]
```

Comment: It should be noted this also means `hello  world` will return two items. That's probably a good thing, but needs care about how "word" is defined.

Comment: @Luaan um, why would it not return 2 items? Test case shows it returning two things.

Comment: @epascarello Eh, there's supposed to be two spaces between the two words :)